# AS3: Copying a Loader from one object to another

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, copy, variable-assignment, loader

I have two classes, call them A and B.  They both contain a Loader object.  In class A I load content into the Loader object.

```
public class A {
    var loader:Loader;

    public function A():void {
        loader = new Loader();
        this.addChild(loader);
        loader.load(...);
    }
}

public class B() {
    var loader:Loader;

    public function B():void {
        loader = new Loader(); 
        this.addChild(loader);
    }
}
```

I need to now assign A's Loader to B's Loader (after the load is complete).

In some other class I have an instance of A and B.  Doing a direct assignment of the loader values doesn't seem to work (when showing B, A's loader content is not displayed).

```
var b:B = new B();
var a:A = new A();

// ... I wait for a's loader to be loaded ...
// ... then ... 
b.loader = a.loader;
addChild(b);
// A's Loader is not shown ...
```

If I do the following, it works:

```
b.addChild(a.loader);
```

But that's not what I want.  I don't want to manage a bunch of children when I know I only have one child but just want to change its content.

Is there a way to copy/assign a Loader directly?  I tried assigning to 'content' but that's read-only.  Is there another way I can do this?  Basically I have an array of Loader objects that all get loaded with images.  I then have a single Loader that's on the stage and I want to assign to it images (Loaders) from my array.

Thanks.

Comment: if it's just images, you can just clone the images' bitmapData and make new ones instead of new loaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up swapping the children to get the same effect.  It's less complicated than I thought it would be.

So basically in B I did:

```
this.setChildIndex(loader,0);
```

This is to make sure the loader is at index 0. (It can be any fixed index but in my case I needed it to appear at the bottom).  It's not necessary to have a loader in B initially but I just put it there to make sure there's something fixed at index 0 (so I don't accidentally remove some other child).

Then when setting A's loader to B I'd just swap out the child at index 0.

```
b.removeChildAt(0);  
b.addChildAt(a.loader,0);
```

It's not exactly the solution I wanted but it's working well so far.

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this for fun:

```
var a:Loader = new Loader();
a.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, aLoaded);
a.load(new URLRequest('A.swf'));
addChild(a);

var b:Loader = new Loader();
b.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, bLoaded);
addChild(b);


function aLoaded(event:Event):void {
    trace('a loaded');
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, aLoaded);
    b.loadBytes(a.loaderInfo.bytes);
}
function bLoaded(event:Event):void {
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, bLoaded);
    trace('b loaded');
}
```

using loader's [loadBytes](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes()) and loaderInfo's [bytes](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#bytes) I create an endless loop where a loads a, loads b, loads a, load b, loads a, loads b...and loop wholes start to appear.

**DON'T DO THAT!**

That is not what you need, you're working with images, so the loader [content](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#content) should be a Bitmap. You can access and clone the bitmapData, given you have permission to access the pixels(e.g. crossdomain policy and a new LoaderContext(true) as the second parameter in the load() call).

So your answer should be as simple as:

```
var a:Loader = new Loader();
a.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, aLoaded);
a.load(new URLRequest('app_image.jpg'));
addChild(a);

function aLoaded(event:Event):void {
    if(a.content is Bitmap){//check if it's actually an image, not a swf
        var clonedData:Bitmap = Bitmap(a.content).bitmapData.clone();
        //do whatever you need with the clone
        //e.g. var dolly:Bitmap = new Bitmap(clonedData);//etc
    }
}
```

It's not the OOP code, it's just something minimal so you can easily get the picture :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  I know I said I'm loading images right now but I realized that I might need to support swfs down the line.  I ended up just doing removeChildAt(0) and addChildAt(loader,0).  It's working so far ...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to create a setLoader method for your b class. something like

```
public class B() {
    var loader:Loader;

    public function B():void {
      // nothing here, unless you really
      // want a b.loader before stting it from outside
    }

    public function setLoader(_l:Loader){
      if(loader) removeChild(loader);
      loader = _l;
      addChild(_l);
    }
}
```

you can then, when a is loaded, call

```
b.setLoader(a.loader);
```

be aware that a.loader will not be a child of a anymore (if you display a, it will be empty), but you will still be able to access it with both a.loader AND b.loader.

tell me if this helps.